# mongoose schema for a dictioanary

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> This is how my database looks

{`"_id" : ObjectId("5905d84ea1b895165b28a2d6"),
    "name" : "risk",
    "email" : "hyuji@gmail.com",
    "cgpa" : "9",
    "stream" : "uio",
    "password" : "password",
    "registered" : [ "reg1", "reg2"],
    "color" : {"reg1":1,
             "reg2":2}`

}

Now i need to write a schema for it

```
var studentDataSchema = new Schema({
name : String,
email : String,
cgpa : Number,
stream : String,
password : String,
registered : [],
color : {}
```

});

How to declare color in above schema, is it correct ??

Comment: Wouldn't `color: {reg1: Number, reg2: Number}` make more sense?

Comment: Number of elements in color keeps on increasing,  was not two element object.